# 17 inches High-end developers laptop for 2019

Tags: laptop, development, high-end

I am looking for a laptop on which I can install linux to do Java development and virtualization. The following configuration comes to my mind.

```
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Processor     | AMD Ryzen 5 or 7 Or Intel i5 or i7 Quad Core |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Memory        | 16 gb DDR4 or more                           |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Storage       | 512 gb NVMe or more                          |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Graphics Card | Low end, since this not a gaming rig         |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Screen size   | 17 inches                                    |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| OS            | Optional to keep cost down.                  |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How much should something like this minimally cost. I am thinking under $1000. Let us collect laptops being sold with similar configurations here.

Answer (score 1):

Look on NewEgg.com: they allow customizing precisely such quantities, when filtering the laptops to display.  The exact search is [here](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100006740%20601286800%20600004346%20601286795%20601301242%20601310336%20600136700%20600337010%20600440394%20601107729%20601183480%20601296059%20601311244&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Order=PRICE&PageSize=36), and as you can see you can currently [get this configuration](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIADT282D7426) for under $500.

Comment: Yes, there search feature is quite feature full. But I did not find a way to additionally filter for NVMe SSDs. I hope they can add that functionality to their web site.